# CollectionView NSURL Session Speed and Reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsurlsession

I'm fairly new to iOS and developing weather App in when I download hourly forecast along with icon of conditions.  I have been able to implement UICollection with NSURL Connection.  However, I'm having issues regarding speed/performance issues regarding NSURL Session.  Here are the two issues:

1) the speed of downloading and presenting the downloaded icons is very slow (and there are extremely small images).  This download process can take anywhere from 5-10 seconds.

2)  when I put a button to reset the collection, all data is reset, however the existing images remain until the new images are downloaded.  Again this can take anywhere from 5-10 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.hours.count;
 }


 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"ConditionsCell";

ConditionsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.conditionsTime.text = [self.hours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.conditionsTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°", [self.hoursTemp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.hoursIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    UIImage * serverImage = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    cell.conditionsImage.image = serverImage;

}];

[dataTask resume];

return cell;
```

}

And here is the IBAction for the button and to reload the CollectionView:

```
 - (IBAction)selectDay:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    self.todayOrTomorrow = @"today";
}
else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
{
    self.todayOrTomorrow = @"tomorrow";
}

self.hours = [self hours];
self.hoursIcons = [self hoursIcons];
self.hoursTemp = [self hoursTemp];

[_collectionViewHours reloadData];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are downloading data in background that, but not updating UI on main thread,try below pattern it willlhelp you

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"ConditionsCell";

ConditionsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.conditionsTime.text = [self.hours objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.conditionsTemp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°", [self.hoursTemp     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.conditionsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:""];//reseting image

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:    [self.hoursIcons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
@autoreleasepool {//autorelease pool for memory release
if (!error) {
//UIImage * serverImage = [UIImage imageWithData: data];//comment this extra variable and can increase memory overhead.

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
cell.conditionsImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];//update UI

});

}}//autorelease pool

}];

[dataTask resume];

return cell;
}
```

it will definetly help you for your first part.

Thanks.